# How to disable Motorola ET1 barcode scanner from pasting output to focused Edittext?

Tags: java, android, barcode-scanner, motorola

I'm trying to integrate `Motorola ET1 bar-code scanner` in my Application. I have created a `DataWidge profile` to receive the `bar-code scanner's` output via intent in my application and processing the same. But my problem is if any `EditText` is in focused state while scanning, then the `inbuilt bar-code scanner` is also pasting the output to that view.

Output via Intent is enough for me, I don't want bar-code scanner to past the output in my views.

I didn't find any option in `DataWidge profile` to do this.

Can someone tell me the way to block this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two way to get the output one is Keystroke o/p and another is Intent o/p that is in DataWidge Profile. So, just disable keystroke o/p it will work.